# Setting the position/width of an NSSlider inside an NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenu, nsslider

I've got an `NSMenu` attached to an `NSStatusItem`, and inside that `NSMenu` I have a `NSMenuItem` for which I've set the `view` property to an `NSSlider` object. That works (it got me what I was after) almost.

The result looks like this:

[NSSlider in an NSMenu as an NSMenuItem.view http://dl.dropbox.com/u/91596/Screenshots/k8tl.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/91596/Screenshots/k8tl.png)

The problem is that I'd like the slider to line up with the menu items above it, so it doesn't look so friggin terrible.

I can't find anything in the apple documentation that says anything about being able to set the position of an `NSSlider` so I assume I'm going to have to wing it by drawing it myself.

Is that a correct assumption? If so, what are some class references/suggested reading links for achieving that result? Or, am I going about this wrong?

While I'm at it - I had to drag the slider in the UI builder to the desired width I wanted - is there any way to programmatically set the width of the slider so it fills up the desired space inside the menu?

Thanks, sorry of these are noob questions - I'm pretty new to ObjC programming.

Comment: The value methods inherited from NSControl.  e.g. setFloatValue:

Comment: CGRectDivide() out a suitable frame, then subtract a little from the edges and align it's origin.x with that of the rest of the controls.

Comment: You might want to reconsider your design - as a user I'd *hate* it to fiddle around with sliders within menus...

Comment: @Jay - you may be right, but the app I'm building is pretty simplistic in nature and just doesn't really have a ton of options/preferences (yet). Making a whole new window or something to allow my user to control the volume of the playback would likely be overkill in this case. Definitely a valid concern though, I'm not thrilled about the idea, but it's the best one I have right now

Answer (score 2):

First make your own `NSView`. Next, put your `NSSlider` in that view. If you need special spacing, adjust the slider in the container view. Or, maybe, twiddle in Interface Builder.